Как автоматически запустить видео с Rutube и VK через iframe. AngularJS
Такая, проблема нужно автоматически запустить видео с Rutube и VK через iframe. AngularJS
С YouTube видео все нормально, но как Rutube и VK не запускается.
Использование autolpay и allow='autoplay', а также добавление ?autoplay=1&muted=1 к ссылке не работают
HTML:
<div id="video" iframeplayer files="{{ playlist.playitems }}"></div>

js (coffeeScript):
#iFramePlayerDirective#

'use strict';

CommonModule.directive 'iframeplayer', ($parse) ->
  restrict: 'A'

  link: (scope, element, attributes) ->

    defaultVolume = 50;

    playitems = $parse(attributes.files)(scope);
    files = [];
    parent = element.parent();
    event = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });

    # Создание iframe для первого видео
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = playitems[0].fileUrl;
    iframe.autoplay = true;
    iframe.allow = 'autoplay; encrypted-media'
    iframe.frameBorder = '0'
    scope.currentIndex = 0;
    element.append(iframe);


Какие есть варианты или обходные пути ?
